# Add dynamic property in JavaScript function

Tags: javascript

By Google, I'm getting how to add dynamic javascript property in an object but here my goal is a little bit different.

I have tried with this code but it gives me `undefined`.

```js
var infoObj = {
  first: "John",
  last: "Doe"
};


function DD() {

  var me = this;
  // because my infoObj will available after x amount of time. (API)
  setTimeout(function(){
  
    Object.keys(infoObj).forEach(function(key) {
      me[key] = infoObj[key]
    });
    
  },2000)
  
  return me;
}

console.log(DD.first)
//undefined
```

Comment: You are not returning from `DD` that's why it is `undefined`. What else do you want?

Comment: Can you clarify what you are trying to do? You never set the `first` property of `DD` so it gave you `undefined`. You always get `undefined` when looking up properties that were never set.

Comment: Just create a new empty obj `var me = {}` and do the same as you are doing in function and return `me`. Because inside the function `this` is `window`.

Comment: This seems like an **over** simplified example of what you're doing. Can you add what your code **actually** looks like and what you've tried?

Answer (score 1):

I think you might a little confused as to what's going on here. Remember, the return of `DD` is a function. Not `infoObj`. So fetching a custom property from an unrun function will always give you undefined.

If you were to run it (`DD()`) you would get the error `Cannot read property 'first' of undefined`. That's because you are not returning anything in `DD`.

Finally, recall that `this` refers to the global object, in this case, a "local global" one, which is considered bad practice (I know this is just a learning exercise, but I'm giving you a full review). Best to move these propreties onto a fresh object (e.g. `var me = {}`)

I would try something like this:

```js
function DD() {
  var me = {};

  Object.keys(infoObj).forEach(function (key) {
    me[key] = infoObj[key];
  });
  return me;
}

console.log(DD().first);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I have edited my question. Actually, my `infoObj` will come from the API service. So returning `me` at the end of the function will not work.

Answer (score 0):

Try this!

```js
var infoObj = {
  first: "John",
  last: "Doe"
};


function DD() {

  var me = this;

  Object.keys(infoObj).forEach(function(key) {
    me[key] = infoObj[key]
  });
  return this;
}

console.log(DD().first)
//undefined
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var infoObj = {
  first: "John",
  last: "Doe"
};


function DD() {

  var me = this;
  // because my infoObj will available after x amount of time. (API)
  
    Object.keys(infoObj).forEach(function(key) {
      me[key] = infoObj[key]
    });
    
  return me;
}

console.log(DD().first)
//John
```